How do I find the min cut on a tree graph such that the source is some subset of the leaves and the sink is the remainder of the leaves?
How do I find the min cut on a tree graph such that the source is some subset of the leaves and the sink is the remainder of the leaves? In particular, is there some simple expression or interpretation for this min cut based on tree properties?

In particular I'm interested in differences in this problem to the analogous problem on graphs that permit loops/cycles.

It is a bit unclear what you are asking, but note that between any two vertices in a tree, there is exactly one path.

That's certainly a true statement, but I'm not sure how to use that to answer my specific problem. I'm considering the case where I have some tree graph with edge weights and I'm trying to find the min cut on that graph such that a proper subset of the degree one vertices of that graph (the leaves) are on one side of the cut while the remained for the degree one vertices are on the other side of the cut. I could clearly do this using Ford-Fulkerson, but I'm wondering whether the fact that I have a tree graph permits a faster algorithm.

For planar graph, finding a min cut is the same as finding a shortest path in the dual graph, so it boils down to a shortest path problem

@caduk When the multiple sources/sinks are taken into account, I'm no longer sure that the associated graph is planar. (To switch to to a standard min cut problem, you'd need to add two new vertices, one adjacent to every source and one adjacent to every sink, unless I'm missing a more clever way.)

@MishaLavrov good point. https://arxiv.org/abs/1105.2228 still claims an almost linear algorithm. Maybe there is something smarter for trees

We should be able to do this with a top-down tree recursion.
Arbitrarily make any non-leaf vertex the root of the tree; label all leaves $1$ or $2$ for which side of the cut they are intended to end up on. Working from the leaves up to the root, we assign each vertex $x$ a pair $(c_1(x), c_2(x))$, where:

$c_1(x)$ is the cost of the min cut of the subtree rooted at $x$, subject to the requirement that $x$ itself is separated from all $1$-leaves.
$c_2(x)$ is the cost of the min cut of the subtree rooted at $x$, subject to the requirement that $x$ itself is separated from all $2$-leaves.

Note that whatever final solution we choose, it must have the property that for each $x$, we have selected one of the min cuts above. (Otherwise, $x$ has a path to a $1$-leaf and to a $2$-leaf, which is a contradiction.)
If $x$ is a leaf with label $i$, we set $c_i(x) = \infty$ and $c_{3-i}(x) = 0$.
If $x$ is not a leaf, and has children $y_1, \dots, y_k$, let $w_i$ be the cost of edge $xy_i$, and set:

$c_1(x) = \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^k \min\{c_1(y_i), c_2(y_i)+w_i\}$.
$c_2(x) = \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^k \min\{c_1(y_i) + w_i, c_2(y_i)\}$.

The idea is that, once we've decided which leaves we want to separate $x$ from, then for each child $y_i$, either we choose a cut that separates $y_i$ from those leaves, or we must cut the edge $xy_i$.
At the end, if $x$ is the root, then $\min\{c_1(x), c_2(x)\}$ is the cost of the min cut of the entire tree.
As written, this algorithm only computes the cost of the min cut, but that is easy to fix if we want the cut itself; merely add to each $c_i(x)$ a set $\mathcal C_i(x)$ of the edges that must be cut to achieve the value $c_i(x)$, and update it at every internal vertex by taking the union of the corresponding $\mathcal C_i(y_1), \dots, \mathcal C_i(y_k)$, together with the edges out of $x$ whose weights we add to $c_i(x)$.
